# Will the files from other partitions show in ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I have a laptop with 1TB HDD and have Windows as my primary OS(on C: drive). I want to install Ubuntu linux in a separate partition on the same drive for learning and testing. But there are certain files that I would like to access from other partitions too like the D: E: and F: partitions.

So my question is, will the files from these **other partitions (other than windows' and ubuntu's)** be accessible in Ubuntu or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I can access all files in other drives from  Ubuntu but I can't access the data from the drive where the Ubuntu is installed because if you see the drive partition ( from disk management in Windows ) where Ubuntu is installed the drive has no letter assigned to it. Generally when we see any other drive it has name so we can access it but the drive where Ubuntu is installed has no name so we can't access it from Windows.
So **You can access every thing *including Windows files* from Ubuntu but you can't access the data from the drive where Ubuntu is installed by using Windows** There should be a way but I don't know how to do that. Thankyou

Comment: thanks. i'll try that out and if it works, i'll mark it as answer. :)

Comment: Windows should have fast boot off and set up as basic partitions to read from Ubuntu.  Reading files should be safe, if writing/changing files, some say not as safe.

Comment: Ok so after dual booting, in file manager>other locations all the drives including ubuntu root partition are showing. Thanks :)